# Only showing 1st item in the List view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im working on Xamarin forms application . When i bind list which contains more than one item ,Only shows the 1 st item of the list and part of the 1 st item as well some characters also missing . Xaml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MCITest.View.IndividualTimeTrackingPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <Button x:Name ="Btn_BadgeINBadgeOut"  Text=""  Clicked="BadgeInBadgeOutClick" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <ListView x:Name="listViewTimeActions"  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding ActionWithTime}"  TextColor="White" /> 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the xaml as shown, also there is no `ItemSource` in that xaml anyway... My guess is you are mistaken about  there being more than one item in the list.

Comment: No checked it in debug mode , there were 5 items

Comment: Show the code where you assign them to the ListView

Comment: Can you show it's view model code and screenshot of the page ?

Comment: Maybe it contains all items, but there is not enough space so you can scroll in the `ListView`? [This might be helpful](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66248/#Comment_66248)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the following lines to your listview's Xaml :

```
 HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding yourBindingSource}"
```